# Why is cons not a member of immutable.this.IndexedSeq[List[List[scala.this.Tuple2[scala.this.Char,scala.this.Int]]]] curr :: result

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given a list of tuples of the form (Char,Int), I want to find the subsets of the list for example if my list was

```
List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
```

Then my function should return

```
List(
  List(),
  List(('a', 1)),
  List(('a', 2)),
  List(('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
  List(('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
)
```

I wrote this function

```
def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
  val curr = occurrences filter { case (c,o) => o != 0}
  if (curr.isEmpty) List(List())
  else {
    val result = for{
      i <- 0 until occurrences.length
    } yield combinations(occurrences.updated(i,(occurrences(i)._1,occurrences(i)._2 - 1)))
    curr :: result
  }
}
```

But I keep getting the following error, and I have no idea why seeing as cons should be a member of List[List[(Char,Int)]]. Any Help would be much appreciated.

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:8: error: value :: is not a member of immutable.this.IndexedSeq[List[List[scala.this.Tuple2[scala.this.Char,scala.this.Int]]]]
  curr :: result
       ^
```

I modified my code to be the following

```
def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]]      = {
  val curr = occurrences filter { case (c,o) => o != 0}
  if (curr.isEmpty) List(List())
  else {
    val result = for{
     (c,o) <- curr
    } yield combinations(occurrences.updated(curr.indexOf((c,o)),(c,o-1)))
    curr :: result
  }
}
```

but Now I get the following error

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : immutable.this.List[immutable.this.List[scala.this.Product    with scala.this.Serializable{}]]
 required:    List[List[scala.this.Tuple2[scala.this.Char,scala.this.Int]]]
  curr :: result
```

Comment: There are a number of different ways to fix the type error you're seeing. So the good news is that, with a small mod or two, your code will compile and run. The bad news is that none of the fixes that I've come across so far will, when applied, produce the output you want.

Comment: Thank's for the help, what are the fixes you used to get it to compile and run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment (above), I found a few different ways to resolve the type conflict but not in such a way that produces the desired results.

```
def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
  val curr = occurrences filter { case (c,o) => o != 0 }
  if (curr.isEmpty) List(List())
  else {
    val result = for {
      (c, o) <- curr
      res <- combinations(curr.updated(curr.indexOf((c, o)), (c, o-1)))
// using occurrences here ^^^^ tends to StackOverflow
    } yield res
    curr :: result
  }
}
```

```
def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
  val curr = occurrences filter { case (c,o) => o != 0 }
  if (curr.isEmpty)
    List(List()) // or Nil for a different wrong result
  else {
    val result = curr.flatMap { case (c, o) =>
      combinations(curr.updated(curr.indexOf((c, o)), (c, o-1)))
    }
    curr :: result
  }
}
```

---

Here's a different approach (that actually appears to work).

```
def crossProd[T](in: Seq[T]*): Seq[Seq[T]] =
  if (in.isEmpty) in
  else in.tail.foldLeft(in.head.map(Seq(_))) {
    for {sentence <- _; word <- _} yield sentence :+ word
  }

def combinations(occurrences: List[(Char,Int)]) : List[List[(Char,Int)]] =
  crossProd(occurrences.map{case (c,n) => (0 to n).map(x => (c,x))}:_*)
    .map(_.filter(_._2 > 0).toList)
    .toList
```

testing:

```
combinations(List(('c',2),('x',3),('#',1)))
//res0: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = 
// List(List()
// , List((#,1))
// , List((x,1))
// , List((x,1), (#,1))
// , List((x,2))
// , List((x,2), (#,1))
// , List((x,3))
// , List((x,3), (#,1))
// , List((c,1))
// , List((c,1), (#,1))
// , List((c,1), (x,1))
// , List((c,1), (x,1), (#,1))
// , List((c,1), (x,2))
// , List((c,1), (x,2), (#,1))
// , List((c,1), (x,3))
// , List((c,1), (x,3), (#,1))
// , List((c,2))
// , List((c,2), (#,1))
// , List((c,2), (x,1))
// , List((c,2), (x,1), (#,1))
// , List((c,2), (x,2))
// , List((c,2), (x,2), (#,1))
// , List((c,2), (x,3))
// , List((c,2), (x,3), (#,1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that because `0 until occurrences.length` is a `Range[Int]`, `result` is not a `List` but is an `IndexedSeq` on which `::` isn't available.

```
for {
  i <- 0 until occurrences.length
} yield f(i)
```

is desugared by the compiler into

```
(0 until occurrences.length).map(i => f(i))
```

and then into

```
Range(0, occurrences.length + 1).map(i => f(i))
```

`map` on a `Range` is inherited from `IndexedSeq` so has the signature (in 2.13 at least):

```
def map[B](f: (Int) => B): IndexedSeq[B]
```

So the overall result type is an `IndexedSeq[List[List[(Char, Int)]]]`.  This result can be converted to a `List` with `toList`.

```
curr :: (result.toList)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for the help :)